# Get JSON values

Tags: json, powershell

After a `Invoke-WebRequest` I get the following context response:

```
$Response = @"
{
  "value":{
    "array":{
      "elements":[
        {"string":{"value":"XX1"}},
        {"string":{"value":"XX2"}},
        {"string":{"value":"XX3"}},
        {"string":{"value":"XX4"}},
        {"string":{"value":"XX5"}},
        {"string":{"value":"XX6"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "type":"Array/string"
}
"@
```

And now I want to save the retrived values, XX1, XX2, XX3, etc.. to a new parameter. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse Json into an object:

```
$parsed = ConvertFrom-Json $response
```

Access elements:

```
$parsed.value.array.elements[0].string.value
```